# Is it possible to remove "Home" link from category navbar in magento 2?

Tags: category-navigation

I want to remove the Home link which we by default get in category navigation bar in Magento 2 version.

Comment: Please add screen-short...

Comment: Hello there, thanks for answers, i think i might have misunderstood it completely, so it was Home button in category navigation before every category listed in catagory navbar in header so i went through some fresh installation and it is not exactly bydefault so then i looked through the theme and it was overridden there, so the file which was overridden for adding Home button in catagory navbar was Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml from Magento_Theme::default.xml layout. so in case it helps anyone in future, Thanks.